# Сортировка массива в swift

Tags: swift

я новичок в swift!  хотелось бы  отсортировать массив var numbers = [1, 2, 4, 7, nil, 90, 54, nil, 22, nil] таким образом что первыми элементами были nil а дальше другие элементы по возрастанию

```
    for i in 0..<numbers.count - 1 {
        for j in i+1..<numbers.count {
            if numbers[j] < numbers[i] {
                numbers.swapAt(i, j)
            }
        }
    }


print(numbers)
```

Comment: Пара вариантов: 1) отделить нули в начало, потом отсортировать остаток 2) использовать сортировку с функцией-компаратором, которая для nil  возвращает результат "меньше"

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь! я сделал все по первому решению, отделил нули в начало! хотелось бы узнать как сделать по второму т,е функция компаранд! если есть примеры кода? спасибо еще раз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
numbers.sort { numLeft, numRight in
  guard let left = numLeft else { return true }
  guard let right = numRight else { return false }
  return left < right
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)